# JS function inside html attribute - all echoed via php. Escaped incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mouseover

I'm trying to run a javascript function inside a html onmouseover attribute to swap pictures. The pictures are all displayed, but the onmouseover doesn't work; I guess I escaped the wrong way (browser displays > )- however I can't find what's wrong
A BIG thank you for any help!

**some of the code :**

```
...
<?php       
            echo "<img src=\"$main_img_small\" alt=\"\" onmouseover=\"<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"mouseover.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">swapImage(0);</script>\">";
                    echo "<img src=\"$var1_small\" alt=\"\" onmouseover=\"<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"mouseover.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">swapImage(1);</script>\">";
                    echo "<img src=\"$var2_small\" alt=\"\" onmouseover=\"<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"mouseover.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">swapImage(2);</script>\">";
    ?>
...
```

**mouseover.js** (stored in same folder):

```
        var phpvar1_large = <?php echo json_encode($var1_large); ?>;
        var phpvar2_large = <?php echo json_encode($var2_large); ?>;
        var phpvar3_large = <?php echo json_encode($var3_large); ?>;
        var phpvar4_large = <?php echo json_encode($var4_large); ?>;

        if(!phpvar1_large){
        var imgArray = new Array(
            '<?=$main_img; ?>'
            );
        }else if(!phpvar2_large){
            var imgArray = new Array(
            '<?=$main_img; ?>',
            '<?=$var1_large; ?>'
            );
        }else if(!phpvar3_large){
        var imgArray = new Array(
            '<?=$main_img; ?>',
            '<?=$var1_large; ?>',
            '<?=$var2_large; ?>',
            '<?=$var3_large; ?>'
            );
        }else if(!phpvar4_large){
            var imgArray = new Array(
            '<?=$main_img; ?>',
            '<?=$var1_large; ?>',
            '<?=$var2_large; ?>',
            '<?=$var3_large; ?>'
            );
        }else if(phpvar4_large){
        var imgArray = new Array(
            '<?=$main_img; ?>',
            '<?=$var1_large; ?>',
            '<?=$var2_large; ?>',
            '<?=$var3_large; ?>',
            '<?=$var4_large; ?>'
        );
        }


        function swapImage(imgID) {
            var theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');
            var newImg;
            newImg = imgArray[imgID];
            theImage.src = newImg;
        }

        function preloadImages() {      
            for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
                var tmpImg = new Image;
                tmpImg.src = imgArray[i];
            }
        }
```

**Browser output:**

```
...
<div id="image">
            <img id="theImage" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41ioC67AdgL.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div id="thumbs">
            <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41ioC67AdgL._SL75_.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="mouseover.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">swapImage(0);</script>"><img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Yrx4v10TL._SL75_.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="mouseover.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">swapImage(1);</script>"><img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41bzT-hN9mL._SL75_.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="mouseover.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">swapImage(2);</script>">

            <br />
        </div>

...
```

So, on the right side of the small picture you see ">

Note: in case you wonder, I am ultimately trying to run this on a wordpress page, that's why the javascript command looks the way it does (seen here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you misunderstood something from the Codex. The script tags are not meant to be used in inline script calls. As the script tags are standard html tags, you can't stuff them into a property of another html-tag. It also says:

> ...you can either set the call for the JavaScript, or the script itself, in the head of  your header.php template file, between the meta tags and the style sheet link....

So your mouseover.js-file should be linked in the `<head>` or before the closing tag `</body>`. Running inline JavaScript is not covered by the entry of the Codex you linked.

To fix your code, you'd have to put the first script tag in the `<head>` and the function call into your inline javascript calls (`onmouseover="..."`). Your code has to look like this:

```
<!-- This should be in your head-tag: -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="mouseover.js"></script>

...
<div id="thumbs">
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41ioC67AdgL._SL75_.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="javascript:swapImage(0);">
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Yrx4v10TL._SL75_.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="javascript:swapImage(1);">
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41bzT-hN9mL._SL75_.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="javascript:swapImage(2);">
</div>
```

However I would recommend you learn about event-listeners in JavaScript or try jQuery for adding mouseover-functions to specific HTML-Elements. Inline JavaScript (`onmouseover=""` etc.) messes up your HTML.